# How do you maintain whitespace formatting within CSV column to be expressed with Selenium send_keys?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, csv, whitespace

Python 3.7
Windows

CSV row data looks like this.

```
data,data,data,some text\n some {0} more data\n even more data\n,data
```

How do you keep the newlines and use `format` when using selenium?

```
payloads = []
with open(filepath,) as _file:
    dgroups = csv.reader(_file, delimiter=','  )
        bpost = {
            'name':dgroups[1],
            'text':dgroups[3],
        }

...

#Selenium section to send the formated text to the browser. 
Textbox.send_keys(payloads[i]['text'].format( payloads[i]['name'])
```

#### Expected

some text

some MYNAME more data

even more data

#### Actual

some text\n some {0} more data\n even more data\n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the csv.reader function is reading in the strings with the backslash being escaped as double backslash:

```
"some text\\n some {0} more data\\n even more data\\n"
```

To solve this issue, you can do the following to made sure newlines are created correctly:

```
Textbox.send_keys(payloads[i]['text'].replace("\\n", "\n").format( payloads[i]['name'])
```